# tz4 curve implementation

Tags: address

The tz4 curve scheduled for the Mumbai protocol upgrade is this one:
https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/016_mumbai.html#cryptography

But it’s not the one used by Ethereum and Zokrates.
What makes the particular choice for the implementation behind tz4 superior and desirable e.g. for zokrates to adapt to this one?

Comment: Just a remark: Zokrates supports multiple curves, including BLS12_381 (see https://zokrates.github.io/toolbox/proving_schemes.html).
Here are few examples how to use Zokrates in Tezos:
1) https://www.dailambda.jp/blog/2021-02-21-zokratez/
2) https://git.tu-berlin.de/niki_blu/bachelorarbeit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the curve the rest of the crypto world has somewhat standardized on, and there is an open Ethereum EIP to support it.

See the motivation and rationale section.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2537

See also
https://hackmd.io/@benjaminion/bls12-381
and
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2333